# Why is it taking longer to log into windows7?

Tags: windows-7, login, performance

I installed windows 7 and it was file for weeks. Recently i created a 2nd user account, installed important updates, installed 1 game and AFAIK that is it. What did it? All three of theses doesnt seem they would cause logging in to take longer (maybe important updates did it?). It takes 90+ seconds to get a fully loaded desktop when it use to take ~30 second. Looking at msconfig and starup i see vmware, dtools, launchy and live messenger (msn). I know i had three of these and maybe all 4 during the last install

how can i find out what made loggin in slow?

-edit- i also installed visual studios rc1 team instead of beta2 and msvs 2008. But i hardly doubt msvs rc1 did it.

Comment: What's your desktop background? (Serious question, there was a bug where a single-color background caused serious login lag, not sure if it's been fixed)

Comment: Phoshi's comment is good - this is a known issue and can add a good amount of time to get from login to desktop.

Comment: same background as i had when it was logging in fine :x

Comment: HAHAHA! Are you serious about that actually being a known issue? Wow, I miss Windows even less now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was because of a network drive. I created a network drive that connect to my VM and obviously it isnt running when my computer first loads so it spends time waiting before loading the desktop (maybe 15seconds or more). After removing i was able to get to my desktop and open a browser within 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

try restarting with "last known good configuration" by pressing F8 while booting

Comment: I havent tried it but AFAIK this config is the 'last known good configuration'. I'll try tonight.